# Macbook pro 2018 13inch display goes to black and pink dots in the display

Tags: macbook-pro, display, touch-bar

I own a Macbook Pro 13inch 2018 touch bar model and suddenly it is showing some issues in the display. (works fine in an external monitor though) For a week, I noticed some pink dots everywhere on my screen and now it goes to a black screen after the OS boots. (Pink lines are visible sometimes even when the during the OS booting)

I don't have AppleCare for this device and when I gave this for a diagnosis to an authorized service provider in Sri Lanka(Since we don't have apple stores or Genius Bars here), they told me that the whole screen needs to be replaced and they cannot check the issue which causes the problem. Another store told me that this could be an issue in the logic board.

My device doesn't have any dents, physical damages or any liquid damages as well. I know that Apple has a tier system when it comes for repairs.

I would like to know any rough estimates for this repair and cause for the issue if anyone has experienced the same.
Also, if someone can tell me the level of the tier(Apple's repairing tear system) this issue falls into that would be great.

For your convenience,  I have attached few videos and pictures of the issue.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tBSV0NtvxZI

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ghc63hbPWnw

[image]

Comment: I don't think what I can tell you is a full answer but: I didn't notice the tiny end of a micro-USB cable lying in between the screen and the keyboard. Even though I slowly closed the lid, the screen got a little splinter and it showed similar screen artifacts to yours. I ended up having it (i.e. the whole screen part) repaired for about 700€ (2017 15" Model).

Comment: @X_841 Did you repair it from the Apple?

Comment: No, I went to an Apple certified shop.